# Prove that at most one vertex can have degree at least |V |/2 + 1.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, trees

Let G = (V, E) be a tree. Prove that at most one vertex can have degree at least
|V |/2 + 1.

I tried to solve this by using a proof by contradiction. I assumed that at least two vertices can have a degree of |V |/2 + 1. But It didn't help that much.
Any ideas?

Comment: Hello :) Try to prove, that they have two common neighbors. What does it mean?

Comment: This is a problem in my discrete math course where it is a violation of academic integrity to get help from websites like StackExchange.  I've flagged this question, but figured it would be helpful to add a comment.

Answer (score 2):

Let $v_1,v_2$ be two vertices of the tree.
Then there is a unique path $v_1,...,v_2$.
Remove any of the edges of this path. We get two connected components, each containing one of $v_1$ and $v_2$.
At least one of the two connected components contains no more than $|V|/2$ vertices. The one $v_1$ or $v_2$ in that component will have to have degree no more than $|V|/2$.